# What is this utility box found above a basement bathroom?

Tags: electrical, utilities, phone-wiring

While investigating putting in a fan, we came across this odd utility box with spring loaded cover. What is it for, and can we remove it?

House was built in 1935. An addition to another part of the house was added in the 1960s.

[image]

Center part looks like ceramic. Insulator?

Four holes, that might be threaded. Center, ceramic? part has a raised section that would maybe prevent mis-alignment of whatever attaches.

Here is a shot of the wire disappearing under the house. Electric wire in foreground gives some scale:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked inside it? Is that an electrical cable going into it?

Comment: Where does the cable go?

Comment: Off into the ether, as far as I can see. I am looking through a small access panel.

Comment: It looks more like a phone line than regular electric wire to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a telephone wire. Also looks like an old style 4-prong telephone jack (inside a fancy metal housing that's a new one on me.) Do you still have an active land-line?

Comment: No land line, but that does seem to be what it is. Here is an image I found on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Four-prong_telephone_jack,_1960s,_front.jpg