# What is this receptacle with four round holes in a square configuration?

Tags: electrical

We just moved into a home built in the early 1960s and have been trying to find an alternative coaxial cable to plug into our modem. (There should be three active lines entering the house. One is in an inconvenient location in a bedroom and there's at least one other in the basement that stops at the crawlspace.)

Might this picture lead to the missing third coaxial cable or is there something else behind the mystery door?

[image]

Comment: see also https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/119931/18078

Comment: That one appears to be a Bell System 497A

Answer (score 14, accepted):

POTS (i.e. plain old telephone service) jack.  This style pre-dates the more common RJ-11 modular type.

[Bell System/Western Electric Phone Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_jack_and_plug#/media/File:Western_Electric_404A_and_283B_four-prong_telephone_jack_and_plug_combination_ca1960.jpg)

[image]